# DropBox Core API Downloading Images for UICollectionView

Tags: dropbox-api

Im new to dropbox Core API. Previously i have some experience with making calls to instagram api's with NSURLSession on the treehouse course I'm on. However I'm stuck here. Iv called the method

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
if (metadata.isDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {

        [self.pathsArray addObject:file.path];

        NSLog(@"----%@", pathsArray);
    }


}

//reloads view to see images
[self.collectionView reloadData];



}
```

Which has given me an array of the file path location. I then wrote

```
NSString *paths = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.filePaths lastPathComponent]]];


 `for (NSString *file in self.filePaths) {

    [self.restClient loadFile:file intoPath:paths];
}`
```

which downloads the images correctly however, because the loaded file method returns null i am unsure how create an array of the downloaded images to display in my UICollectionViews cell?

Answer (score 1):

The `loadFile` method in the Dropbox for iOS Core SDK says:

```
/* Loads the file contents at the given root/path and stores the result into destinationPath */
- (void)loadFile:(NSString *)path intoPath:(NSString *)destinationPath;
```

This means the downloaded content (for the file on Dropbox at `path`) is saved to the local filesystem at the local path `destinationPath`.

You can use this delegate method to know when this is done:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath;
```

To get the content for the downloaded file once you've been notified it is done, you need to read the downloaded file from the local file system. For example, you might load it using [`NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:), or whatever the relevant next step is for you.